# Spring batch and Spring cloud data flow - postgres - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID not found

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID not found, when i am running spring batch task using spring cloud data flow. I read that invalid task execution error is because of not using same data source for spring batch and spring cloud data flow. But in my case i get this error even after using same postgres datasource.

This is my DataSourceConfiguration class

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.DefaultTaskConfigurer;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.TaskConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

public class DataSourceConfiguration {
    @Value("classpath:schema-postgres.sql")
    private Resource schemaScript;

    // This data source is for spring batch to create its table to track jobs
    // spring batch and spring cloud data flow will use this datasource
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource postgressDataSource() throws SQLException {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://***/***");
        dataSource.setUsername("***");
        dataSource.setPassword("***");
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator(), dataSource);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript(schemaScript);
        return populator;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate postgressJdbcTemplate(final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    // This data source is used for poc
    @Bean
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        // INIT in connection string will run data.sql script during in-memory h2
        // startup
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:data.sql'");
        dataSource.setUsername("***");
        dataSource.setPassword("***");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("h2DataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskConfigurer taskConfigurer() {
        try {
            return new DefaultTaskConfigurer(postgressDataSource());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my batch configuration

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.builder.CompositeItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

import com.csx.batch.listener.JobCompletionNotificationListener;
import com.csx.batch.mapper.ReportInfoMapper;
import com.csx.batch.process.ReportInfo;
import com.csx.batch.process.ReportItemProcessor;
import com.csx.batch.process.ReportWrapper;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTask
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import({ DataSourceConfiguration.class })
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    // one reader
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<ReportInfo> reader(@Qualifier("h2DataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<ReportInfo> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setSql("SELECT * FROM REPORTINFO");
        reader.setRowMapper(new ReportInfoMapper());

        // next call will made to app api and get report information
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReportItemProcessor processor() {
        return new ReportItemProcessor();
    }

    // multiple writers
    @Bean
    public CompositeItemWriter<ReportWrapper> writer(@Qualifier("h2DataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
        List<ItemWriter<? super ReportWrapper>> delegates = new ArrayList<>();
        // this writer step is optional
        delegates.add(reportWriter(dataSource));
        delegates.add(reportInfoWriter(dataSource));
        // add another writer to send report as email/NAS input

        return new CompositeItemWriterBuilder<ReportWrapper>().delegates(delegates).build();
    }

    // writing to report table
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<ReportWrapper> reportWriter(@Qualifier("h2DataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<ReportWrapper>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql("INSERT INTO REPORT (REPORT_NAME, REPORT_DATA) VALUES (:reportName, :reportData)")
                .dataSource(dataSource).build();
    }

    // updating reportinfo report_date column
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<ReportWrapper> reportInfoWriter(@Qualifier("h2DataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<ReportWrapper>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql("UPDATE REPORTINFO SET REPORT_DATE = :nextReportDate WHERE ID = :reportId").dataSource(dataSource)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener).flow(step1)
                .end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(ItemReader<ReportInfo> reader, ItemProcessor<ReportInfo, ReportWrapper> processor,
            CompositeItemWriter<ReportWrapper> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<ReportInfo, ReportWrapper>chunk(1).reader(reader).processor(processor())
                .writer(writer).build();
    }
}
```

Running above job using inbuilt spring scheduler, and it works as expected and add tasks into the task_execution table as expected.

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BatchJobScheduler {
    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 8000)
    public void runBatchJob() {
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("jobId", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();
        try {

            jobLauncher.run(job, params);

        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobRestartException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In below image we can clearly see that task_execution_id 3 and 6 are as expected from application scheduler. Where as task_execution_id 4 and 5 are from spring cloud data flow and it causing task execution id not found. Even though it is adding entry into this same table (for both spring batch and spring cloud dataflow have same postgres datasource).

[image]

Dependencies used for spring cloud data flow application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.***</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-data-flow-poc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-cloud-data-flow-poc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.pivotal</groupId>
                <artifactId>pivotal-cloudfoundry-client-reactor</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.EnableDataFlowServer;
import org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.KubernetesAutoConfiguration;

@EnableDataFlowServer
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration.class,
                KubernetesAutoConfiguration.class}
)
public class SpringCloudDataFlowPocApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudDataFlowPocApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Spring cloud dataflow application properties has the same datasource as mentioned above in the spring boot application.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://***:5432/***
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***

spring.cloud.dataflow.features.streams-enabled=false

spring.cloud.dataflow.features.tasks-enabled=true

spring.cloud.dataflow.features.schedules-enabled=true
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

Here is the spring cloud dataflow execution:
[image]

Error I am getting, when starting spring batch job task from spring cloud dataflow is

```
2020-05-28 17:31:47.369  WARN 98668 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 5 not found
2020-05-28 17:31:47.370  INFO 98668 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2020-05-28 17:31:47.371  INFO 98668 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2020-05-28 17:31:47.372 ERROR 98668 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.listener.TaskLifecycleListener   : An event to end a task has been received for a task that has not yet started.
2020-05-28 17:31:47.373  INFO 98668 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-28 17:31:47.376  INFO 98668 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-05-28 17:31:47.378  INFO 98668 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

Please help me in understanding why I am getting this taskexecution id not found error, even though I am giving same postgress datasource to both spring batch and spring cloud dataflow applications.

Another subsequent question i have is, if i run spring batch in clustered environment, will spring cloud dataflow scheduler handle clustered environment? Or will spring cloud scheduler trigger spring batch in multiple noded?

Comment: Are you sure Spring Batch is using your postgres db for its job repository? Do you see Spring Batch meta-data tables in your postgres db? I see you created a `taskConfigurer()` that returns `new DefaultTaskConfigurer(postgressDataSource());`, have you tried creating the same for Spring Batch, aka creating a `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and passing `postgressDataSource()` to it?

Comment: I see all these tables in my postgres client batch_job_execution, batch_job_execution_context, batch_job_execution_params, batch_job_instance, batch_step_execution, batch_step_execution_context and other flyway, task related tables too. @Mahmoud Ben Hassine

Comment: I have created new task configurer, because spring batch was confused between 2 data sources(h2 and postgres). This configuration i have explicitly for spring batch application only, not spring cloud dataflow app as it has only one data source.

Comment: Well, your batch configuration imports `DataSourceConfiguration` which defines two datasources, so you still need to specify which datasource to use for spring batch. Do you see Spring Batch meta-data tables in your postgres db? Are they being filled in when you run your job? It's worth adding a DefaultBatchConfigurer and passing postgressDataSource() to be sure there is no confusion. Have you tried that?

Comment: return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(postgressDataSource()); did not resolve it. Yes metatables are getting populated with both spring batch and spring dataflow. It works perfectly fine with, inbuilt scheduler in spring batch app but not by triggering from spring cloud dataflow task.

Comment: Hello @Sujith.   Can you upgrade to the latest Spring Cloud Dataflow 2.5.1.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Task 2.2.3.RELEASE and retry.   This way we can make sure this isn't a resolved problem.    If it continues then we can dig in a little deeper.  Thanks!

Comment: @Glenn Renfro - after updating dependencies to latest versions, getting this error.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while creating ClassLoader for file. 

Here is the maven path i am using to register in spring cloud dataflow : maven://com.***:spring-batch-boot-poc:1.2.0

Comment: Hello @Sujith I'm not seeing the exeption you are reporting.  Using https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/v2.5.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dataflow-server as a guide I created a quick demo dataflow instance.  This is so that I could test launching a job against a Postgres DB on a local machine. Here is the project I created: https://github.com/cppwfs/demodataflow

Comment: Thank you, for the quick demo project. I will check how this is different from my setup. Can you also please share the job you are triggering from this above spring dataflow?.

Comment: I used the timestamp-batch app that is available via the app bulk import. 
maven://org.springframework.cloud.task.app:timestamp-batch-task:2.1.0.RELEASE
This is modeled after the batch sample in Spring Cloud Task.  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/batch-job

Comment: Thank you, will make changes according to these repos. I will share my observations

Comment: The demo is more of a guide more than an exact how to.   Look at the link to the SCDF repo for more detail.